# How to make sure signals reach logger function?

Tags: c++, c, linux, logging, signals

I need to write a set of C++ functions, which will be kept in a separate library file, which will be used for crash-logging of different Linux applications made by other people. Such functions must install signal handlers in order to function.

How can I make sure that the signal will reach my logger function if the application they will be used in will install their own signal handlers?

Comment: Check if you can get hold of "How core dump is generated" and mimic/add plug-in at that point. This is easier said than done, since you will have to handle things in kernel level.

Comment: Thank you for the input, kumar_m_kiran :)

Answer (score 0):

You can implement functions such as `signal`, `sigaction`, `sigprocmask`, etc. in your library, so that they are used instead of the ones defined in glibc in order to prevent overriding your signal handlers and blocking your signals.

The application still can circumvent that by calling the corresponding syscalls directly.